# How to mount crashed windows harddrive partition when using linux live cd ubuntu.

Tags: ubuntu

So my hard drive crashed and it didn't work with windows dell inspirion; and i didn't have a backup ops. i know but i have a lot of picture there which i need ! ! After few research i was able to boot with a cd of Linux live Ubuntu but now when it boots up it doesn't show any partition of windows; I tried imaging the hard drive but its not doing anything. any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I would like to know if there is anyway or command if I could mount the windows data when operating ubuntu

Comment: ok to start off, so sorry to hear about the drive crash! it sucks when that happens. Now, to mount a windows partition onto linux, it's actually pretty easy but could you get on your terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and type in "sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL". Print that out and post it for us. It will tell us all the available partitions and disk formats. The key is to figure out what format your disk is in so we know if it can be mounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you show us your disks with:

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
```

You'll see a bunch of disk paths that will start with /dev/sd where the  is going to be a letter. Ubuntu gives letters in alphabetical order to each drive so if you have two physical drives, you will see an sda and sdb.

Now, you should be able to identify your partition, the one you want to mount, given that it will tell you the size and format type (and name). So once you find that drive (a, b, c...) you need to also find the partition number which is the number after the lower case letter.

With this info, you want to create a mounting point on your drive (you need to tell ubuntu where you want to place the partition) and you do that by creating a directory (for this example, lets call it mounting_folder):

```
mkdir /media/mounting_folder
```

Last part is mounting it. Assuming it's ntfs which is likely, you can mount your drive by running:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sd<X><number> /media/mounting_folder
```

You should now be able to access your files and folders and move them around as you please.

Good luck!

Comment: it got stuck? like the terminal is frozen or your entire computer? try the simpler command "sudo fdisk -l"

Comment: however i typed second and third command then it said input/output error

Comment: and ntfs is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or its' a SoftRaid hardware. In the first case run chkdsk on windows .

Comment: right, try "sudo fdisk -l" because that will tell us exactly what drive you have. it may not be ntfs which is why it's giving you that second error

Comment: es i did it says .. dev/sda3 is HPFS/NTFS/exFAT and same for dev/sda2 and 1... i think all my files are in sda3 cause it says its 403GB.

Comment: now we're getting somewhere. so from what i gather you have one harddrive, a, and 3 partitions. Partition 3 the one you want. If that's the format then we should definitely be able to mount your drive (if not corrupted). Can you confirm that the "mkdir" command worked? If so, type this in "sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222 /dev/sda3 /media/mounting_folder"

Comment: yes mkdir works and the sudo command did work but it said some like  for many more details, say man 8 mount . . and it didn't really mount anything or i did see any new folders

Comment: ok, run that command in my previous comment. This one:

sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222 /dev/sda3 /media/mounting_folder

Comment: it said the same thing and gave me information on say man 8 mount

Comment: So i tried a lot of other thing to mount my partition sea and it didn't work.. do you have any idea if i create a .img file from disk manager utility in ubuntu.. I would be able to recover my file.. but what is the good software or program to retrieve those data from .img file? do you have any idea

Comment: you could try but I don't know much on that subject.

Comment: so finnaly i think you are right.. all i had to do was restart my laptop and i was able to do it all .. thanks myan